# Determining caller context from/for python __getattr__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an object that captures a given value, and attempt to access attributes from that value through the wrapping object using the object's `__getattr__` method.

Works as I expect, except for 1 part. I need to understand if the value passed to `__getattr__` is a method, or just a property.

With a simplified version of what Im working with,

```py
class Wrap:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        # if ???:
            # print('returning method None')
            # return lambda *args, **kwargs: None
        # else:
            # print('returning prop None')
            # return None


class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


try:
    print(type(Wrap(Something()).nothing))
except Exception as exc:
    print('prop failed')
    print(exc)
print('---------------------------------------------------')

try:
    print(type(Wrap(Something()).nothing()))
except Exception as exc:
    print('empty method failed')
    print(exc)
print('---------------------------------------------------')

try:
    print(type(Wrap(Something()).nothing('here')))
except Exception as exc:
    print('param method failed')
    print(exc)
```

---

If I uncomment the `return None`, it works for the property, but fails for the methods (understandably):

```
<class 'NoneType'>
---------------------------------------------------
empty method failed
'NoneType' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------
param method failed
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

If I uncomment the `return lambda`, it works for the methods, but returns `function` (obviously) for the property:

```
<class 'function'>
---------------------------------------------------
<class 'NoneType'>
---------------------------------------------------
<class 'NoneType'>
```

So what conditional can I put for the `if ???:` that would allow me to always return a `None`?

I've tried using inspection and sys to get the frames, but it only shows `<method>` as the caller, and context just shows the full (`print(type(Wrap(Something())...))`) line.

So aside from a poor, hacky solution of getting frame context and running it through regex, Im not sure what I could do to solve this.

Is there a different magic method that would help altogether? I've considered swapping this for a `__getattribute__`, but havent tried it yet. Ideas?

Comment: `__getattr__` is called like this: `foo.bar` would do `foo.__getattr__("bar")` and `foo.bar()` would do `foo.__getattr__("bar")()`. Note that both call `__getattr__` with `"bar"` but the latter one calls the return value. It's `getattr`, not `callattr`. I'm not sure why you would do this, but perhaps asking that question would be better. If you were just curious, no problem! I've asked the same thing too before.

Comment: @GeeTransit Thanks. I get that Im doing a **get**attr, and not **call**attr. Of course that would make it easier if such existed... =)

Really, Im fine with `__getattr__` not calling the underlying attr itself. I just need to understand if the value passed is INTENDING to be a callable.

PS: I appreciate the comment rather than the two others downvoting and leaving

Comment: Aw, no problem. It'd be cool if there were some way to distinguish stuff like this. Though I don't need this right now, it might come up in the future and hit me at the worst of times lmao. Have a good day :D

Comment: I don't understand what the significance of `value` is in your `Wrap` class. If you're trying to be a proxy for the value's methods, you could inspect it's attributes to see if they are callable or not. But trying to inspect the stack is doomed, as you'll never be able to handle a case like `x = obj.method; x()` well. But perhaps you should just return a callable in all cases?

Comment: It is indeed, intended to be a (kind of) proxy for the wrapped value. I have a lot more going on in the original method and code than just this. I was just trying to get a minimum viable example for question's sake. I am already checking if `item` exists in value, and returning that if it was found to do whatever is needed outside this wrapping class. Imma play with your example though, since you got me curious

Comment: A proxy you say... You can just apply `__getattribute__` and make it return `getattr(self.value, name)` where `name` takes the place of `item` in your example (since it's technically just a string the attribute getter wanted). If want to get even better, you can add dunder methods like `__repr__` that just call it on the wrapped value.

Comment: I've actually got several of the extra `__*__` methods on it already. And first line in this method on my actual class is indeed a `attr = getattr(self.value, item, None)` so I can determine if it exists or not. I've had this class for about a month now. Im handling the part where `attr` exists, and it works well. It's the "not" part that was iffy, and I was looking to finally solve the last piece I needed for that, tonight. =)

Comment: I may still play with `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`, to see if it would simplify the overall code, but Imma have to add that to my list and save it for another day. I appreciate it @GeeTransit and @Blckknght

Answer (score -1):

Using this for my `if` solves the issue for this question, and my original issue.

```py
stack = inspect.stack(1)[1]
context = stack.code_context[0]
obj = [*stack.frame.f_locals][-1]

result = re.search(obj + r'.*\)\.' + item + r'(\(.*?\))?', context)
if result.group(1) is None:
    return None
else:
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: None
```

Comment: You think you've solved your problem, but you haven't. That `obj` computation is completely wrong (and pointlessly convoluted for what it does do), as is the regex.

Comment: "That obj computation is completely wrong" Mkay, how so? `stack.frame.f_locals` is a `dict`, I convert that to a `list`, grab the last item on said list. Of course I could simply it by dropping the slice and extra `[0]`, but this is still not "wrong"... As far as the regex, it works exactly how I need it to: finds the instance of `obj`, searches until I reach the instance of `item` (as given by `__getattr__`) and grabs a group possibly containing parens or values. As far as Im concerned, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: But of course, as I mentioned in my answer, Im open to alternatives if you were to suggest one, instead of just saying "this is wrong"

Comment: It's a dict, but what do you think you're extracting from the dict? The last entry in that dict (in whatever order the dict happens to be in) may be something completely unrelated to what you're looking for.

Comment: As for the regex, what it's searching for after the period is okayish (as far as regex-based approaches to this kind of thing go, which is still full of problems), but what it's searching for before the period doesn't make sense.

Comment: Even if you fix those problems and write the best source-code-inspection approach possible (way harder than it sounds), you're still going to run up against the fundamental limits of source code inspection approaches, particularly the limit that you need source code to inspect (so it won't work interactively, in a debugger, in a .pyc-only module, etc.), and you'll miss anything your source code inspection doesn't recognize, like `getattr`, or things being accessed by names your inspector doesn't recognize.